# what are the advantages of using Geoserver?

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver

We are currently using the Geoserver for storing the spatial data of map,But i am not understanding how it works and how its better.

> what are the *advantages* of using **Geoserver**?

Comment: Your question is not very precise. Are you asking about http://geoserver.org/? And advantages compared to *what* other solution?

Comment: @ scai  yes, i am  talking about geoserver.org

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-do-we-need-mapserver-geoserver-to-present-data-from-spatial-database-to-web